# How do I import smart card certs to use with Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, ms-office, keychain, smart-card

My goal is to send a signed email using a smart card (CAC). On [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-a-digitally-signed-or-encrypted-message-a18ecf7f-a7ac-4edd-b02e-687b05eff547), I found a help page that shows how to use sign the email using a cert, but I can't figure out how to select the smart card with the certificate.

I'm using a SCR3310 card reader, I have the drivers installed.  I can use the card ready to access web sites that require the cert.  How do I now access the smart card from Outlook?

Here is a screenshot showing the cert selection in Outlook.
[image: outlook, digital signing, no cert found]